# Have to require Vue component TWICE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript, vue.js, require

The short question I have: based on the below code, *why do I have to 'import' the components below twice to get my code to work*?

I am working in a pretty locked-down environment, so cannot use Webpack or .vue SFCs at the moment, or npm (for all intents and purposes).

I've cobbled together a working version of a small vue app using typescript files, but am confused why it worked :S.

**I have to import the component file, *then* require it as a component.**  I'd like to clean this up if I could, as we will be rolling this out as a P.O.C. with developers that are also just learning Vue, so I'd like to avoid bad practices at the start if I could.

index.ts

```
import * as Vue from "vue";
import * as Apple from "./App";                  <-----  
Vue.component('apple2', Apple.default);          <-----  wat?

let v = new Vue({
el: "#app",
components: { Apple},                            <-----
template: `
<div>
    <apple2/>                                    <-----
</div>`,
data: {
    name: "World"
},

});
```

App.ts

```
import * as  Vue from "vue";
import * as fred from  "./Hello";                    <----
Vue.component('fred2', fred.default);                <----

export default Vue.extend({
name: 'Apple',
template: `
<div>
    <fred2 :name="name" :initialEnthusiasm="4"/>     <-----
</div>`,
data() {
    return { name: "World" }
},
components: { fred }                                 <-----
});
```

Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="scripts/vue.min.js"></script>
  <script data-main="scripts/build/index" src="scripts/lib/require.min.js"> 
  </script></head>
   <body>
     <div id="app"></div>
   </body>
```

tsConfig

```
{"compileOnSave": true,
"compilerOptions": {
"module": "amd",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"noImplicitAny": true,
"noEmitOnError": false,
"outDir": "./scripts/build",
"removeComments": false,
"sourceMap": true,
"target": "es5",
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"esModuleInterop": true
},
"exclude": [
"node_modules",
"wwwroot"
],
"include": [
"./scripts/**/*"
]

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixin up two different concepts, when you do this:

```
Vue.component('apple2', Apple.default);
```

You're actually registering the component definition object (Apple.default) with the name apple2 with the global Vue instance, making it available to all the components that are rendered by the previously referred Vue instance. In this case you could remove this part of your code in the index.ts:

```
components: { Apple}
```

And in theory your app should still work.

But because you're using typescript you can make your app work as if it was using a module system, allowing you to import the used sub-components in each parent component, allowing you to do something like this:

App.ts

```
export default const component = {
    template: '<div>My component</div>'
}
```

index.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import component from './App';

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        'my-imported-component': component
    }
});
```

And in your template:

```
<div id="app">
    <my-imported-component/>
</div>
```

This would be, in my opinion a better approach because that you won't pollute the global Vue instance with all your components, but it's a matter of taste and what works for your scenario.

For more information take look at this link:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html